# How to prevent Unity's ScrollRect from moving as the size of the content changes?

Tags: unity, c#, text-based, scrolling

I'm writing a Text-RPG and I have set up a ScrollRect where new paragraphs and choices are added and removed at every turn. This makes the size of the Content change constantly, which I handle with a Content Size Fitter.

To prevent the player from losing track of the last paragraph he was reading before making a choice, I'd like to keep it in the same position relative to the screen no matter what changes in the Content. However, this is not possible due to the **clamped** setting of the ScrollRect's Movement Type. I want to keep the clamped behavior to prevent endless scrolling, but I need to find a way to make it work while keeping the last paragraph's position.

Here's a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Current Behavior (Wrong)]
[image: Desired Behavior (Correct)]

Setting the ScrollRect's Movement Type to **unrestricted** causes the behavior I'm looking for. However, I can't allow the content to be scrolled endlessly. If there is a workaround for clamping an unrestricted ScrollRect that could be a solution... I'd love to hear about it!

I've also considered instantiating an empty block that takes the size of the choices block to cover the space marked in red. However, that causes more problems since the player might select a choice while the scroll is not entirely at the bottom. I really don't know how to make that work.

Comment: Why not try adding new paragraphs first and then removing the select block?

Comment: The new paragraph will have a different size than the choices block, so there will still be movement in the ScrollRect content.

Comment: Maybe make the reading text and response choices separate elements. Or maybe calculate and remap "manually" the anchoredPosition of content.

Comment: On a second thought there is a chance it could be as simple as caching anchoredPosition of Content, do changes, restore to the cached anchoredPosition.

Comment: If the size of the new paragraph is too small (sometimes it might be just a word, such as "Success!") the content will still be clamped at the bottom, causing the movement I'm trying to avoid. I can apply the cached anchoredPosition but it won't work because of the forced clamped behavior.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand the problem but maybe clamp it manually between what is "bigger", the max position of content vs cached anchor.